# Python dictionary key is not identified

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a method like following,

```
@staticmethod
def get_repo(tenant_id):
    """

    :param int tenant_id:
    :return: GitRepository object
    :rtype: GitRepository
    """
    AgentGitHandler.log.info(AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories)
    AgentGitHandler.log.info("Tenant ID %s" %tenant_id)
    for key,value in AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories.iteritems():
            if tenant_id == key:
                    AgentGitHandler.log.info("Key Matching")
                    AgentGitHandler.log.info(AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories[key])
            AgentGitHandler.log.info("Key %s : value %s ", key,value)
    if tenant_id in AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories:
        return AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories[tenant_id]
    AgentGitHandler.log.info("False condition")
    return None
```

I am trying to get call the above function like following,

```
git_repo = AgentGitHandler.get_repo(tenant_id)
git_repo.scheduled_update_task.terminate()
```

tenant_id parameter value is -1234 which is in the dictionary as a key.
But I am getting a response like below.

```
2015-06-01 13:44:54,979:INFO:Processing Tenant unsubscribed event: [tenant] -1234 [application ID] single-cartridge-app
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:INFO:{u'-1234': <modules.artifactmgt.git.agentgithandler.GitRepository instance at 0x1cbeb00>}
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:INFO:Tenant ID -1234
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:INFO:Key -1234 : value <modules.artifactmgt.git.agentgithandler.GitRepository instance at 0x1cbeb00>
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:INFO:False condition
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:INFO:GIT_REPO None
2015-06-01 13:44:54,980:ERROR:Error processing 'ApplicationSignUpRemovedEvent' event
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/apache-stratos-python-cartridge-agent-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/modules/subscriber/eventsubscriber.py", line 103, in run
    handler(event_msg)
  File "agent.py", line 294, in on_application_signup_removed
    self.__event_handler.on_application_signup_removed_event(event_obj)
  File "/mnt/apache-stratos-python-cartridge-agent-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/modules/event/eventhandler.py", line 355, in on_application_signup_removed_event
    AgentGitHandler.remove_repo(application_signup_removal_event.tenantId)
  File "/mnt/apache-stratos-python-cartridge-agent-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/modules/artifactmgt/git/agentgithandler.py", line 414, in remove_repo
    git_repo.scheduled_update_task.terminate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scheduled_update_task'
```

Why is the if condition getting false ?

Comment: your `get_repo` function returns `None`. And then when you do `scheduled_update_task` on the `object of type None`. You get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scheduled_update_task'`

Comment: Yes. The problem is why get_repo returns None. 
You can see that the value for tenant_id -1234 exists in the __git_repositories dictionary.

Comment: You are not triggering key match, so this means that key is not in AgentGitHandler.__gite repositories . Log this dict content.

Comment: @Elric The dict content is logged in the second line :

{u'-1234': <modules.artifactmgt.git.agentgithandler.GitRepository instance at 0x1cbeb00>}

Comment: Irrelevant, but 1. you don't need `return None` unless there is any code to follow. 2. It's not a method, it's a function.

Comment: Your code is confusing. You define function like `def get_repo(tenant_id):` there is no `self` there. And you call it like `AgentGitHandler.get_repo(tenant_id)`. Is there any other method with the same name on AgentGitHandler class?

Comment: @0xc0de Sorry it is a static method. I have now changed it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to iterate over AgentGitHandler.__git_repositories, ie. class attribute and not an attribute of its object?

Comment: I iterated because I wanted to debug the code.

Comment: Please show the log statement, and possibly the whole class code....

Comment: @0xc0de Thanks for the responses. You can view class from following link.
https://github.com/apache/stratos/blob/master/components/org.apache.stratos.python.cartridge.agent/src/main/python/cartridge.agent/cartridge.agent/modules/artifactmgt/git/agentgithandler.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79312/discussion-between-0xc0de-and-anuruddha-lanka-liyanarachchi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in the doc string that `tenant_id` is an int, and it appears to be one in your log, but your dictionary key is a unicode string, `-1234 != u'-1234'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the issue